# Any way to fail build in TeamCity by result of cppcheck analysis

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, static-analysis, cppcheck

I use cppcheck for static code analysis in my project and TeamCity for continuous integration. It would be nice if build server didn't build the project when cppcheck finds some errors or warnings. Is there any way to make build fail by result of cppcheck analysis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a cppcheck dev. The cppcheck command line flag --error-exitcode might help.

Comment: I use this flag, but the fact is that I need also treat cppcheck warnings as reason to fail build, not only errors.

Comment: It works fine! I got what I need by combining flags: --enable=all --error-exitcode

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of cppcheck requires that you pass an actual return code to `--error-exitcode`; otherwise, it fails by telling you no such flag exists.

```
cppcheck --error-exitcode=1 ...
```

The above will exit with code `1` in the event something is found.